# In polymer 1.0 Importing polymer-button in a custom element gives error

Tags: javascript, polymer-1.0, paper-elements

I have written a simple Polymer custom element and want to use the `paper-button` element inside it. My code looks like this:

```
<link rel="import" href="bower_components/Polymer/polymer.html">
<link rel="import" href="bower_components/paper-button/paper-button.html">

<dom-module id='chart-label'>
  <template is="dom-bind">
    <template is="dom-repeat" items="{{lables}}">
      <input type=checkbox checked="true" id="checkb" value={{item}} name="check" on-change="checkChanged"><b>{{item}}</b>
      </template>
  </template>
  <script>
    Polymer({
      is: 'chart-label',
      buttonStates: [],
      properties: {
        buttonstates: {
          type: Array,
          value: [],
          notify: true,
        },
        lables:Array
      },
      ready: function () {
        for (var i = 0; i < this.lables.length; i++) {
          this.buttonstates.push(true);
        }
      },
      checkChanged: function (e) {
        var it = e.model.item;
        var index = this.lables.indexOf(it);

        console.log(index + " index checked");
        if (e.target.checked) {
          this.buttonstates[index] = true;
        } else {
          this.buttonstates[index] = false;
        }

//      for (var i = 0; i < this.lables.length; i++)  {
//        alert(this.buttonstates[i]);
//      }

        //console.log("this.buttonstates"+this.buttonstates);
        this.fire('checked',this.buttonstates);
      }
    });
  </script>
</dom-module>
```

When I try to test this code, it fails with the following error:

> Uncaught NotSupportedError: Failed to execute 'registerElement' on 'Document': Registration failed for type 'dom-module'. A type with that name is already registered.

What am I missing here?

**Note** I am writing this code on Polymer 1.0 **

Answer (score 0):

I had messed up the polymer verrsions in my code. I fixed it after building the new app all together.